# Repeat until + menu in pascal

Tags: freepascal

I've got error for this code. Can somebody please tell me which part is wrong?
This program should continue until the user exit the program. Eg: if they choose 1 then after choice is execute they should be given the menu again until they choose to exit the program.

```
program calculator;

var
  a, b: integer;
  c: real;
  choice :integer;


  begin
     a:=5;    b:=3;
   writeln ( ' Welcome to computer program');
   repeat
     writeln ( ' Please select your choice ( 1-5 ) ');
     writeln ( ' 1: addition');
     writeln ( ' 2: subtraction');
     writeln ( ' 3: multiplication');
     writeln ( ' 4: dividion');
     writeln ( ' 5: exit');
     readln ( choice );

   case choice of

   1: begin
        a:=a+b;
        writeln ( 'a: ',a);
        readln;
      end;

   2: begin
        a:=a-b ;
        writeln ( 'a: ',a);
        readln;
      end;

   3: begin
        c:=a*b ;
        writeln ( 'c: ',c);
        readln;
      end;

    4: begin
        a:=a div b ;
        writeln ( 'a: ',a);
        readln;
       end;

    5: begin
       writeln ( ' Exit ');
       halt;
       end;

  until choice = 5;   // I've got error here but I don't know what to    change. 

 end.
```

Comment: @exo_1what happens exactly? try using a debugger to step through your program.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `end;` for the `case of` statement. That's why it is not compiling.

In addition to that:
You define the exit value twice. You check choice in the `until` statement and in the `case` construct. When `choice` equals 5 you write 'Exit' and execute the `halt` command which stops the program. So the condition in the `until` statement will never be true. Thus it's unnecassary.

You've got two ways to get rid of one of those checks:

1. Replace the `repeat..until choice = 5` by an infinite loop. For example `while(true) do begin ... end;`
2. Remove the case statement for the value of 5. And execute `writeln( ' Exit ' )` beneath the `repeat..until` loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally be able to execute the code. ^_^